# Change class properties on mouse enter

Tags: javascript, html

I'm busting my head on this script because I don't understand why it isn't working because it's supposed to be very simple, I just want to show and hide a certain div or change it's properties.

Javascript:

```
function show(x){
    var y = document.getElementByClassName(x);
    y.style.display= 'block';

}
function hide(x){
    var y = document.getElementByClassName(x);
    y.style.display = 'none';

}
```

HTML:

```
<a href='http://dreamspark.e-uvt.ro/dreamspark/'target='_blank'onmouseover='show('divdreamspark')'onmouseleave='hide('divdreamspark')'>
```

CSS:

```
.divdreamspark {
    display: none;
}
```

I don't see what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: `getElementByClassName` returns **collection** of elements, you've to iterate over them

Comment: `getElementByClassName` returns `array-like` nodelist...Use `loop` or `[0]` if only one element is there in the `DOM`

Comment: not elementBy its elementsBy correct sentence is var y =document.getElementsByClassName(x).[0]; y.style.display = 'none';

Comment: it should be `getElementsByClassName` plural

Comment: Typo there, missing `s`. Should be _getElement**s**ByClassName_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple issues:

1. You have messed the single quotes in the markup.
2. There is a typo with the method `.getElementsByClassName` missing `s` in the `Element` part.

---

update the markup:

```
<a href='http://dreamspark.e-uvt.ro/dreamspark/'target='_blank' 
   onmouseover='show("divdreamspark")' 
   onmouseleave='hide("divdreamspark")'>
```

Update the js:

```
function show(x){
    var y = document.getElementsByClassName(x)[0]; // <---missing s in Element
    y.style.display= 'block';
}
function hide(x){
    var y = document.getElementsByClassName(x)[0]; // <---missing s in Element
    y.style.display = 'none';
}
```

If the element is single then suffix `[0]` at the selector *(although class selector returns a collection)*. If you are dealing with multiple elements then you have to use loop to iterate and hide each one of them.

```js
function show(x) {
  var y = document.getElementsByClassName(x);
  [].forEach.call(y, function(i, el) {
    el.style.display = 'block';
  });

}

function hide(x) {
  var y = document.getElementsByClassName(x);
  [].forEach.call(y, function(i, el) {
    el.style.display = 'none';
  });
}
```

Comment: **Not just typo**, you should add this as comment

Comment: Thanks for the tips, but I can't use " " quotation because all the <a href> is inside an echo I can use only single quotation ' ;

Comment: @AlexandruIanas then escape it with `\\`.

Comment: Thanks, it works, you're an absolute genius!

Comment: @AlexandruIanas You are welcome and glad this helped you.